# Mobile website too slow on the phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a prototype for a mobile section of a website. It uses no dynamic staff, just jQuery and Foundation 4. When I test the site in the iphone's browser, it's very very slow to load and to respond to touches. Can some experienced folks please tell me all things to make sure the site loads and operates faster on the mobile device?

All my images are saved "for web", so they shouldn't be a problem. Could it be slow because my CSS style sheet is very lengthy? I am not an expert at combining and applying one classes to a lot of things yet, so may be I have too many id-s and separate classes? Would that be a big deal in this case though? Also, could it be slow because I am using Foundation, jQuery and a Flexlider plug in and each of them has their own multiple style sheets and .js files? Should I throw away any files I am not using from their folders? Am I on the right track and what else can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, yes, yes, your website is slow because you're using tons of everything, get rid of it and use small html/css/js

Answer (score 4):

There are some things which helped me to make my mobile app more faster. I had the same issue as you, the screen response was very low.

---

**Get rid of every unused code**

I had a lot of commented code and files that i actually didn't use. This includes css styles that aren't used.

**Do you even need classes or Ids?**

Looking at my app, i had almost on any element a class or Id. Were i instead could use a element selector. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) some more info about the selectors. Follow the DOM structure. 
 I mostly used a class for groups and Ids for one specific element(which i almost never needed).

**Check if you have css styles that doesn't add something**

Sometimes you have multiple styles that doesn't actually add anything to it. A great example is using a `float: *;` and `display: inline-block;`. When using both of these on one element has no extra function as float makes the element inline-block by default.

**optimize  you script**

With this i mean, see if you can shorter you codes with the same functionality. Using two almost identical functions? short them to one function. Also using premade function of your script language will really help you to make your code faster. So don't create your own sort function, but use the premade function.
For help on optimizing you code, i suggest you to take a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

**jQuery selectors**

Make your jQuery selectors more specific. For example:

 You may have a div with class content.

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Instead of selecting it with

```
$('.content')
```

You could use

```
$('div.content' )
```

jQuery can now restrict the search to DIV elements only.
More info fore more efficient jQuery selectors [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/)

**Store determenation code**

When you get information, for example screenWidth minus the width of a other div, and you using this more then once, store it! This way your webpage hasn't to do the calculate over and over and can just get the variable.

**Don't use 'big' plugins when using half of it**

When you only use a small part of a plugin you're using, it's better to find or a other plugin or code it yourself. Loading the plugin files might harm your performence, would be a shame if it actually wasn't even necessary.

---

This is just a global view were I had a big advantage on and I hope you can find a fine use for this.

Feel free to correct me when I'm wrong.

Comment: "This way you say to look at every div, not every element" This is not exactly how the selection works afaik as it's evaluated from right to left. First all elements with `.content` are selected and the all others dropped that don't match the rest of the criteria. What I want to point out: merely by increasing the specifity you don't gain any performance benefits.